# Access a control inside a Listbox DataTemplate

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, listbox

I'm developing a Windows Phone 8 and I have a single selection Listbox and this `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="LocalizationItemTemplate">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="8" Background="#FF003847" Height="80">
        <Grid x:Name="contentGrid" Margin="4">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="90*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <CheckBox x:Name="selectedCheck" Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="20" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="20"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="locationName" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="10,34,0,34" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="0"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

**How can I access the `selectedCheck` CheckBox programmatically?**

Comment: That's why you use MVVM.  You'd bind your listbox to a collection of Location objects, and you would bind Location.Selected to the checkbox.  In your ViewModel, you could easily locate whatever the user selected and move on.  No messy poking about in the visual tree.

Comment: Didn't you apply binding to CheckBox? It would be tedious to go through the VisualTree.

Comment: I think the right answer is to apply binding to Checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

```
    private T FindElementInVisualTree<T>(DependencyObject parentElement, string name) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parentElement);
        if (count == 0)
            return null;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parentElement, i);

            if (child != null && child is FrameworkElement && (child as FrameworkElement).Name.Equals(name))
            {
                return (T)child;
            }
            else
            {
                var result = FindElementInVisualTree<T>(child, name);
                if (result != null)
                    return result;

            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Usage:

```
ListBoxItem item = list.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(list.SelectedItem) as ListBoxItem;
CheckBox check = FindElementInVisualTree<CheckBox>(item, "selectedCheck");
```

But, I think you need to bind `IsChecked` property on `selectedCheck` object to manipulate on it

```
<CheckBox x:Name="selectedCheck" IsChecked={Binding Checked, Mode=TwoWay} ...
```

Comment: This is definitely a tedious process due to bad programming style. But you did a great work.